# Nodejs + typescript class inheritance

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, routes

Im building a simple rest api in typescript+expressjs. I wanted to build it with classes and i'm stuck on the part with routing classes.
My idea was to build a base class (baseRouter) that could be extended by specific routers (IndexRouter). But trying to do this, i end up registering routes from baseRouter and not the IndexRouter.
What am i doing wrong?

```
export class baseRouter {
    protected static _inst: baseRouter;
    protected _router: express.Router;
    protected _routeBase: string = "/base";

    protected constructor() { }

    public static route(router: express.Router) {
        if (typeof this._inst === 'undefined') this._inst = new this();
        this._inst._router = router;
        this._inst._registerRoutes();
    }

    protected _registerRoutes() {
        this._router.get(this._routeBase, this._doGet);
        console.log('Calling base route');
    }

    protected _doGet(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
        res.status(200);
        res.send('isBase');
    }
}

export class indexRouter extends baseRouter {
    protected _routeBase = "/index";

    protected _registerRoutes() {
        this._router.get(this._routeBase, this._doGet);
        console.log('Calling index route');
    }

    protected _doGet(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
        res.status(200);
        res.send('isIndex');
    }

    protected _doPost(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
        res.status(200);
        res.send('isIndexPost');
    }
}
```

Entry method to both classes is .route(router).
Ideally my solution to my understanding was going to be like:

```
BaseRouter.route() -> calls baseRouter._registerRoutes() -> ...
IndexRouter.route() -> calls indexRouter._registerRoutes() -> ...
```

Is this achievable without redeclaring .route() function every time?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error. When calling `BaseRouter.route()` it calls `BaseRouter._registerRoutes` and when calling `IndexRouter.route()` it calls `IndexRouter._registerRoutes` (though there's no need to have this method twice)

Comment: Odd, i updated the code with console.log's and it clearly displays to me the "calling base route" twice in console while running node.

Comment: It runs fine for me on node as well. What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: Typescript - 2.1.6
Node - 6.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
if (typeof this._inst === 'undefined') this._inst = new this();
```

When you first call `BaseRouter.route()` this line sets the `BaseRouter._inst` static member.
But because `IndexRouter` extends `BaseRouter` it also inherits the static members, so `IndexRouter._inst` also exists and so in that line an instance of `IndexRouter` won't be created.

The reason that it runs well in playground is that it targets `es5`, and you're probably targeting `es6`.
The difference is that when targeting `es6` the classes will be converted into `es6` classes where the static behavior is different.

To fix this you can do:

```
public static route() {
    if (typeof this._inst === 'undefined' || this._inst.constructor !== this) this._inst = new this();
    this._inst._registerRoutes();
}
```

---

#### Edit

As far as I'm aware there's no trick for having a "static polymorphic this member`, for example this fails:

```
class BaseRouter<T extends BaseRouter<any>> {
    protected static _inst: T;
    ...
}
```

Because:

```
Static members cannot reference class type parameters
```

So I'm pretty sure that you'll have to stick with: `static _inst: baseRouter`.

You can try redeclaring the member in `IndexRouter`:

```
class IndexRouter extends BaseRouter {
    protected static _inst: IndexRouter;
    ...
}
```

You can also have a generic getter:

```
class BaseRouter {
    private static _inst: BaseRouter;
    protected static _getInstance<T extends BaseRouter>(): T {
        return this._inst as T;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, im targetting es6, since node is (or at least should) support most of its features. Thanks for explaination and your code works perfectly.

Comment: One more question, im going to keep it here, cause its somehow related.
Since _inst is an inherited instance, that should be a reference to the "current" class object, how do i set the type of _inst to the right class?
Right now its the "baseRouter" in all of the subclasses (easy to test - you dont get protected/private methods completion)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not supported yet. There's an issue for it: [Polymorphic "this" for static members](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863).

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem :) Shame i cant upvote more than once.